# Can we (in principle) obtain molecular bound systems by modelling fundamental particles and their interactions?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, molecules, elementary-particles

Is it possible, at least in principle, to start with the Schrodinger/Dirac/Klein-Gordon equations to model elementary particles and their interactions and to obtain in the end molecular bound systems? In other words, is it possible (in principle) to deduce the laws of chemistry starting from the laws of elementary particles?

Comment: It is the other way. In chemistry they use so many expections from what is predicted from physics starting with the filling of electron shells. The octet rule has no foundations from ohysics. Even the important Pauli exclusion principle is a empirical principle.

Comment: octet is basically comes from energy bands. Pauli exclusion is not empirical, it was derived for fermions of half integer spin

Comment: @Ariana Not right. The spin-statistics theorem establishes that half-integer spin particles cannot be quantised with symmetrical states, but it doesn't explain why all particles must be either symmetrical or antisymmetrical. Also, there does not exist a physical explanation for wavefunction antisymmetry. So the exclusion principle very much remains empirical.

Comment: To the original question: this is effectively what those who apply quantum chemistry methods such as [density functional theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory) do.

Comment: This question shows how quantum chemistry is ignored by physicists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, yes, this is done in theory of atoms and molecular bonds, also known as quantum chemistry. One can begin with Schroedinger's equation and derive much of the observed properties of atoms and molecules - their energy, spectra, bond lengths and stable arrangements of atoms in space (shape of molecules) which reproduce some chemical ideas of molecules (say, the typical angles between C-H bonds - for example, 120 degrees in methane, which is a tetrahedron).

In practice, the calculations get too demanding to do exactly for small molecules, so there are approximate methods, which have some success, but not always. Chemistry is still not merely 'applied theory of Schroedinger's equation' and probably won't be for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but due to the difference in time and space scales, we have specific models for specific problems to model. Some examples are: First principles modelling (ab-initio approaches), DFT, molecular dynamics; the first two start with Schrodinger's equations and work their way up, molecular dynamics is used in bigger systems using data from the DFT or first principles (usually as a bridge to scale size and time).